# why does gcc (installed via brew) not recognize glib (also installed via brew)?

Tags: c, gcc, homebrew, glib

test.c

```c
#include <glib.h>
int main() {}
// test program to verify glib can be included
```

```
brew update
brew install gcc
brew install glib
gcc-13 test.c
```

I get this error.

```
test.c:5:10: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <glib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I tried specifiying include and linking directories but no luck

```
gcc-13 test.c -I /opt/homebrew/lib/glib-2.0/include/ /opt/homebrew/include/glib-2.0/ -L /opt/homebrew/lib/glib-2.0/
```

Comment: gcc-13 test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0)

okay so this works and the code compiles, but is there a better way?

Comment: Well, have you looked whether `glib.h` exists in the paths you provided?

Comment: What's wrong with `gcc-13 test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0)`? The purpose of `pkg-config` is to make it easy to figure out the correct compilation flags across systems. If you run `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` in a shell you'll get the correct flags on _your_ system, which probably differ from the ones you tried.

Comment: I was thinking that gcc would already have the correct channels for including glib and compiling without any flags. Is this not possible? Is that something one might even want?

I get all of these flags from pkg-config:
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.78.3/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.78.3/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.42/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.78.3/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl

Comment: No, it is normal that one has to add `-I`/`-L`/`-l` flags for all libraries that a C++ project uses and it is normal for a build system to detect the correct paths via e.g. `pkg-config` or some build system specific method. Noone writes `gcc` commands by hand on the command line except for simple experiments. If libraries are installed system-wide (e.g. with `apt` on a Debian system to `/usr`, not to `/opt`), then the default search paths will be enough (but `-l` flags are _always_ needed).